# Unknown Provider Error on Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am receiving an unknown provider error on a directive I made. I just began learning about directives so I apologize in advance if I made a very obvious mistake.

The directive is supposed to create an element it creates using a factory.

The div causing the error:

```
<div annotation-display tree="{{tree}}"></div>
```

The directive that angular cannot find:

```
angular.module('trees').directive('annotationDisplay', ['annotationFactory', function(annotationFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tree: '=tree'
        },
        transclude: true,
        compile: function(element, attrs)
        {
            var htmlText = annotationFactory.createAnnotationHtml(tree);
            element.replaceWith(htmlText);
        }
    };
}]);
```

The factory:

```
angular.module('trees').factory('annotationFactory', ['', function() {
    var factory = {};
    factory.createAnnotationHtml = function(tree) {
        console.log("in");
        var out = "<p>";
        d3.tsv.parseRows(tree.data, function(data) {
            var previousNERTag = "";
            for (var row in data) {
                var wordData = data[row];
                var NERtag = wordData[7].substring(wordData[7].length,3);
                if (previousNERTag != NERtag) {
                    previousNERTag = NERtag;
                    if (NERtag === "")
                        out+="</span>";
                    if (NERtag === "PER") 
                        out+='<span class="Person">';
                    if (NERtag === "ORG")
                        out+='<span class="Organization">';
                    if (NERtag === "LOC")
                        out+='<span class="Location">';
                }
            }
            out+='</p>';
        });
        return out;
    };

    return factory;
}]);
```

I loaded the trees module in the main app and its definitely there because my controller in trees is working fine.

Solved,

`.factory('annotationFactory', ['', function() {`
to 
`angular.module('trees').factory('annotationFactory', function() {`

Comment: try doing: `restrict: 'EA'`

Comment: Isn't a div an element?

Comment: taken from angular docs:
The restrict option is typically set to:

'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name

Comment: you might need to have `template` or `templateUrl`. Like in angular docs:
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
  };

Not sure if compile does that.

Answer (score 0):

`restrict: 'E'` Means your directive is an element. 
`restrict: 'EA'` Means your directive would be an element or an attribute.
As you are using it with `div` it works as an attribute. 
If you want to use it as element then change

```
<div annotation-display tree="{{tree}}"></div>
```

to

```
<annotation-display tree="{{tree}}"></annotation-display>
```

Comment: Tried E and EA, same error, I also tried with 
<annotation-display tree="{{tree}}"></annotation-display>

However, setting the directive to